# Text won't stay in the same format as written in HTML document

Tags: html, list, text, formatting

My HTML document has a bunch of text written down in a list like so;

example

test

this

way

Yet when the page is loaded its all one jumbled line. How do I format it so it's the way it's written above but without the spacing? Using

```html
<p>
```

only creates more spacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use line breaks:

```
Text<br>More text<br>Even more text
```

These act as carriage returns and have them on separate lines. Here's an example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hr3aywy2/). Read more at the article at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br).

Comment: Thanks but do I have to put this for each line? It's a lot of text. Is there a faster way to format this?

Comment: @wavey you could use JavaScript to programmatically insert the breaks